# Both absolute and relative paths can be used when uploading files. But when accessing those files later I must use only relative paths. Why?

Tags: php, image, upload, relative-path, absolute-path

Locally, in PHP when I use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) for uploading files (say images), Both **absolute** and **relative** destination paths work.

After uploading those images into the specified destination path, it is only possible to display those images in a webpage using **relative** path - **absolute** path will not work.

Why?!!

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
PHP Version 7.1.1
IDE: NetBeans IDE 8.2

---

Project structure:

```
example
│
└───Source Files
    │
    └upload_display_example
     │  images
     │    │(empty)
     │    └
     │  display_photo.php
     │  photo_upload.php
     │
```

---

**`photo_upload.php`**

```
<?php
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Both $absolute and $relative paths work
function get_path() {
   // return $absolute = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . 'example' . DS . 'upload_display_example' . DS . 'images' . DS;
   return $relative = './images' . DS;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $tmp_path = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $photo_name = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    $photo_path = get_path() . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_path, $photo_path)) {
        header("Location: display_photo.php?img=$photo_name");
        die();
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Cannot move photo to permanent location.');</script>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="photo_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <p><input type="file" name="file_upload" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

---

**`display_photo.php`**

```
<?php
defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Only $relative path will work
function get_path() {
   //  return $absolute = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS . 'example' . DS . 'upload_display_example' . DS . 'images' . DS;
    return $relative = './images' . DS;
}

if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $photo_name = $_GET['img'];
    $src = get_path() . $photo_name;
    echo "<img src='$src' width='200' height='200' />";
}
?>
<br />
<br />
<a href="photo_upload.php">Upload a new photo</a>
```

Comment: Because you're confusing web root with filesystem root

Comment: @MarkBaker In other words, is it OK that **only** relative paths can be used when referencing image files in `<img src />`

Comment: If you're serving files via <img src="">, then it must be from the web root, not from the filesystem root

Comment: @MarkBaker I have just understood that I am *confusing web root with filesystem root*. After googling I found that the absolute path (corresponding to the web root) must start with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and not `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as I did. So it must be *in my case* : `$absolute =  DS . 'example' . DS . 'upload_display_example' . DS . 'images' . DS;`.